Modded APK displaying errors with minimal edits
I'm completely new to APK modding and I'm trying to edit some strings on a random app I use.
I use Apktool to decompile and recompile the APK and uber-apk-signer to sign and zipalign it.
Then, I install the modded APK on BlueStacks to test it out: it starts up fine, but when I try to access certain parts that (I suppose?) require some kind of verification, the app displays an error (no crash). This does not happen with the original unmodified app.
I tried to use apksigcopier because I figured it was a signature issue, but I couldn't get it to work because the recompiled APK's size is for some reason larger than the original, even when I don't make any changes!
I'm a little lost here... How do people manage to mod APKs and get them to work? I can't even change a single string without 80% of the app crashing...

What app is it? What strings did you change? What did the error say?

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I'd rather not say the name of the app for privacy reasons, but I can say I changed a string inside the res/values-xx folder (where you can find all the translations for an app). I just wanted to change the welcome message. The error was a very generic one, didn't convey any info at all. I also tried doing the same thing with other apps and sometimes the app just straight up crashes. Am I doing something wrong with my procedure here? Am I using the right tools?

If you can't provide enough details for other people to reproduce your problem, then Stack Overflow isn't a good fit for your question.

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I just wanted to know if the process I'm following is good or not. Maybe the app has got some kind of tamper protection or maybe I'm not doing the right things

I mean, even if I take the app, decompile and recompile it without making any changes, it crashes on me

May be the app perform self-checks regarding the used signing certificate or it uses PlayIntegrity when it uses a certain server and then recognizes that the integrity of the app is invalidated because of your changes. There are multiple way detecting a manipulated APK. The minimum you should do is checking logcat for errors and other unusual output from the app.

@Robert I did! It looked good to me :( I'll check again tomorrow

Sounds like signature integrity check. Judging from info from your comments.
If the original apps work well on emulator, then I think it may not be Play Integrity check, as suspected in one of the comments.
Perhaps the app has it's own signature integrity check.
Before reverse engineering/patching any apk, you must first check if it is protected by any commercial protection, before proceeding. For this, use APKiD
If it isn't protected by any commercial product and it looks basic, then you have options to either use pre-built tools to bypass integrity checks, or manually patch it by yourself.
For prebuit tools (easy path), you can use

LSPatch's sign kill
MT Manager/NP Manager sign kill
SimpleHook Sign bypass
Or, you can use publicly avaliable frida scripts to bypass sign check, along with frida gadgets



How do people manage to mod APKs and get them to work? I can't even
change a single string without 80% of the app crashing.

That's what signature/self integrity checks are for. People use it so that modders can't mod their products. While it doesn't prevent modding completely, it at least makes it difficult.
Basically, the app checks for its own integrity in its code — if it has been modified or not. You need to patch that check first before you can even change anything inside the apk statically.

Thank you so much! This answer is exactly what I was looking for!
